# How can I add the Spatial Analyst ArcToolBox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-9.3

I tried to add the Spatial Analyst ArcToolBox by right click and selecting 'Add Toolbox' but I cannot find in any folder the available toolboxes. They seem that they have disappered. I work with ArcGIS 9.3.
Any help please?

Comment: The Spatial Analyst toolbox is a separately purchased add-on to ArcGIS.  If you have a license for it, then you need to register it through the license manager in order for it to become available.

Comment: I have the license and I have registered all extensions already.

Comment: i have got all things right. but the problem is that when i use the spatial analyst tool hydrology>fill it says error. so do you have any idea why i am getting the error.

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Please add comment in question section. This is not the answer

Answer (score 5):

In addition to getting the Spatial Analyst license activated, you also need to have selected that extension when you ran the ArcGIS Desktop install disc.  That *should* have caused the toolbox to be there. So maybe it's just not properly installed.

Comment: As I noted above the extension is activated.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I solved the problem by reinstalling ArcGIS!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure it is enabled it in the extension manager. Customize (on the menu bar) > Extensions.  Select the extensions you want to enable and then close it.  That toolbox should already be visible in "toolboxes > system toolboxes" in the catalog window (maybe only ArcGIS 10). In 9.3 you may have to then turn the toolbar on. Customize > Toolbars > 'Locate the toolbar'.  Then i believe you can dock it or just let it float. From there you should have access to all of the tools within that extensions toolbox.

If when trying to enable the extension (customize > extensions) you get a prompt that "There is no [extension] license currently available" then you may have installed it wrong.

Comment: The toolbar of Spatial Analyst is enable while I cannot see the toolbox in ArcToolboxes. The starnge thing is that I can see it when I select to create a new file but not if I open an existing one.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I solved the problem by reinstalling ArcGIS!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add the toolbox if it is in the Toolboxes folder (usually something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes") by right-clicking on the white background part of the ArcToolboxes pane and choosing "Add Toolbox".

Answer (score 0):

Olá, já habilitei a ferramenta Spatial Analyst, no entanto ao salvar os comandos na barra Options>General>Extent>Cel Size, eles não ficam salvos. O que pode ser feito?

Google Translate (Portuguese>English)

> Hello, I already enabled the Spatial Analyst tool, however when saving
>   the commands in the Options> General> Extent> Cel Size toolbar, they
>   are not saved. What can be done?

Comment: Hi Mariane, welcome to GIS SE. You have posted your question as an answer. Please re-post as a new question, otherwise you will probably get no help. Also, I would suggest translating to English before you post.

Answer (score 0):

Also another method I know which this can be done is to go to Customize(software task bar)> Toolbars then select Spatial Analyst.
After that go to the same customize click on Extension, then check every box you can find in there